# How to increase the font size of the mahapps.metro Textbox's watermark text

Tags: .net, wpf, mahapps.metro

How increase the font size of text of the Watermark ('8 hours') in the WPF code below:

```
<TextBox x:Name="txt8HoursArm1"
                                     Margin="5"
                                     Grid.Column="1"
                                     IsTabStop="False"
                                     Style="{StaticResource PrimaryInputTextBoxStyle}"
                                     Controls:TextBoxHelper.UseFloatingWatermark="True"
                                     Controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="8 Hours"
                                     IsEnabled="False"
                                     Text="1"
                                     GotFocus="txt_GotFocus"
                                     PreviewTextInput="txt_PreviewTextInput"
                                     TextChanged="txt_TextChanged" FontSize="14" />
```

Please see the below image of textbox

[image]

Comment: There is no direct property to set the FontSize of the Watermark, but it seems you can override the watermark style: https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/issues/2491#issuecomment-302401391

Comment: Hi nemesv, I am new in WPF. You have provided the link. But I am not understand that how to implement this code in my form. Can you explain thoroughly.

Comment: Add an xmlns referencing mscorlib alias sys to your window tag. ( Scroll a little down from the top of that link to see the exact text to paste in. ) Change your textbox tag so it is not self closing. Inside the tags paste the markup from the same post <FrameworkElement.Resources>
    <sys:Double x:Key="FloatingWatermarkFontSize">14</sys:Double>
</FrameworkElement.Resources>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can just create your own style achiving the same with full control over everything:

```
<Style x:Key="TaggedTextBox"  TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Hotpink"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="32"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                <Grid>
                    <TextBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" />
                    <TextBlock Foreground="Lime" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="10" Margin="5,2" Text="{TemplateBinding Tag}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

use:

```
<TextBox Style="{StaticResource TaggedTextBox}" Tag="Cheese" Text="Spaghetti"/>
```

look:

[image]

Comment: Thanks nemesv, Andy, mm8 & Denis Schaf. Specially thanks for "DENIS SCHAF" whose provided code has solved my problem. In your provided code, I have just increase FontSize in <TextBlock> tag and it solved my problem. Note: I observed that for only one line of code, I need to write above mentioned 17 lines of code.

Comment: @DineshKudale glad i could help. One thing in general: i ve observed many people struggeling with 3 rd party control libraries here one SO. all working hours to solve issues with them while implementing it themselves would have been a lot easier and offer them full control over what they do. So in future instead of blindly relying on those libs consider just coding it yourself and save you a lot of trouble! :)

Answer (score 2):

if you are using `mahapps.metro version >= 2.0` then do this:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

    <sys:Double x:Key="MahApps.Font.Size.FloatingWatermark">15</sys:Double>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

if your `mahapps.metro version < 2.0` it is:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

    <sys:Double x:Key="FloatingWatermarkFontSize">15</sys:Double>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

[Source](https://mahapps.com/docs/guides/migration-to-v2.0#list-of-deleted-renamed-and-new-font-sizes)